# Does google supports TestCafe along with Puppeteer?, if Yes, then Why?

Tags: automated-tests, puppeteer, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I am new to these two tools and was discussing them with one of the colleagues and he suggested that there are google supports TestCafe despite the fact that it is focused on Puppeteer development.

Why would Google support TestCafe, is that just because of TestCafe support multiple Browsers? or something else? or this statement is not true.

Comment: What do you mean by Google supports TestCafe?

Answer (score 3):

Google does not support TestCafe specifically. TestCafe uses a proxy server that injects test JavaScript code into page being tested. Test code uses whatever api browser provides.

Answer (score 3):

Puppeteer (or Google) does not explicitly support TestCafe. TestCafe is using the [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) (and not even *puppeteer*) to control the browser.

TestCafe can either use `xvfb` to simulate a display server to run Chrome in or you can specify to start chrome in `headless` mode (code from [docs](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/browsers/testing-in-headless-mode.html)):

```js
testCafe
    .src('path/to/test/file.js')
    .browsers('chrome:headless')
    .run();
```

So you won't need to install puppeteer to run tests in Chrome using TestCafe.

---

If you still want TestCafe to use `puppeteer` instead to control Chrome, there is an unofficial plugin called [testcafe-browser-provider-puppeteer](https://github.com/jdobosz/testcafe-browser-provider-puppeteer). You can specify that you want to the plugin like this (taken from the [docs](https://github.com/jdobosz/testcafe-browser-provider-puppeteer#usage)):

```js
testCafe
    .createRunner()
    .src('path/to/test/file.js')
    .browsers('puppeteer')
    .run();
```

Comment: I want to mention that this is not an official TestCafe repository. I don't recommend you use it since TestCafe already supports Chrome DevTools Protocol inside. TestCafe supports headless mode, device emulations, taking screenshots. All this functionality works similarly to Puppeteer since it has the same core. If this functionality does not satisfy all your needs, feel free to create feature requests or contribute to TestCafe repository https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe

Comment: @AlexKamaev Thanks for clarification, I put that information into the answer.